# Upload video thumbnail on video upload with ng-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I'm uploading a video to my server ng-file-upload using https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

It all works, but I'd like to store a thumbnail on the server too to display on the webpage in the "poster" tag of the HTML5 player (as documented here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_poster.asp)

```
<video controls poster="/images/w3html5.gif">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

So to do that, I need to get thumbnail and upload that to the server too, so I can pull back the URL to put in the "poster" tag.

I notice in the documentation there's a directive to get a thumbnail preview of a video:

```
<div|span|...
 ngf-thumbnail="file" 
 ngf-size="{width: 20, height: 20, quality: 0.9}" 
 ngf-as-background="boolean" 
>
```

But how do I get that thumbnail as an image and upload that to the server too? Is that possible?

Comment: Use `Upload.resize(image, ...)` service call to resize the image to the thumbnail size and then send it to the server.

Comment: Hi Danial. This seems to work for images, but does this work to grab a thumbnail from a video too? I can't quite figure that out. This is a great library, by the way, I use it all the time!